# Non-associative algebras and determinant over 3 by 3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, non-associative-algebras

I have a non associative algebra $A$ that is not unital. And I have three by three matrices $X$ with coefficients over $A$ with a matrix product $*$. I'd like to define something like the determinant of the matrix. Do you know any definition that goes in that direction?